# Transforming a filter string into a C# delegate

Tags: c#, linq, parsing, reflection, delegates

I have a set of classes which I am using for a Data Access Layer for some clients. As part of the data access I am allowing a set of filters to be sent in this format:

```
"{Member[.Member....]}{Operator}{Value}"
```

I would like to turn these strings into delegates for use in a LINQ query like this:

```
.Where([delegate returned by a factory])
```

Here is a more concrete example:

```
IEnumerable<Parent> parents = GetSomeParents();
string filter = "Child.Id=5";
var expression = FilterFactory<Parent>.GetExpression(filter);

parents = parents.Where(expression);
```

expression would contain the delegate: `parent => parent.Child.Id == 5`

Is there a way using reflection to construct the FilterFactory in a Generic way to handle any member path I send in? Paths with indexing aren't required, but would be nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes absolutely! This is a really fun thing to do too.

One way you can do this is to use the [LINQ Dynamic Query Library](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) and get the expression compiler they have in there. I also have something very similar in my project [MetaSharp](http://metasharp.codeplex.com).

But you could also do it yourself if the syntax or features don't quite match what you're wanting. The general idea is that you need to parse the string and build up an Expression tree that represents what you are parsing. In .NET the expression tree objects can be found in System.Linq.Expressions. Once you have your tree you can call Compile() on it and it will be dynamically compiled into a delegate right then. Try reading about the State Machine and Visitor patterns to figure out the best way to parse an arbitrary expresssion like you have above.

PS I would not recommend using regular expressions!

Comment: This is basically what I would say. It's going to be a bit of trial and error getting your expression builder running though! =D

Comment: The Dynamic Query Library works fine. I hooked it straight into our Linq to NHibernate DAL classes and it plays rather nicely